# Foundation navbar menu button not populating

Tags: web, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to set up a web app with foundation and I'm having some trouble getting the navbar to work properly. It works fine when the screen is large. The buttons all appear on the navbar. When I shrink the screen, the buttons disappear as expected and the menu button appears. Unfortunately, the menu button doesn't work. Clicking on it has no effect. The script and css links in my page are valid. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
      <link href="/foundation/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="/foundation/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>TITLE</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/foundation/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>$(document).foundation();</script>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
            <h1>Title</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="small-0 medium-4 columns"></div>
         <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">search</div>
      </div>
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
         <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name"></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="left">
               <li><a href="#">left</a></li>
            </ul>
         </section>
      </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

unable to post it as code gives me a connection error because of script code